# Unable to consume Web Api Service from .NET 3.5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-3.5, webclient, asp.net-3.5

I have a web api service that I've created as part of a separate project, and I can connect and consume the service without any problem by using HttpClient in .NET 4 and 4.5.  However, HttpClient is not supported in .NET 3.5, and I need to be able to consume this service from an existing .NET 3.5 application.  I've tried using WebClient, but it doesn't work.  Here's my code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");

string serialisedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DATA);

var response = client.UploadString(URI, serialisedData);

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
```

I've tried the solutions using WebClient offered here: 
[Call web APIs in C# using .NET framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397865/call-web-apis-in-c-sharp-using-net-framework-3-5) and here:
http://www.thepicketts.org/2012/11/how-to-access-webapi-from-a-net-3-5-client-in-c/

and this solution includes HttpClient code, event though it isn't even supported: 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1982540.aspx?Consume+Web+API+in+project

**What am I doing wrong when trying to connect to web api using .NET 3.5?**

Comment: If you have told us what exception you got, we would have told you what you are doing wrong. :)

Comment: No exception, the response object comes back empty.

Comment: Discovered the problem: there was an action filter setup for the web api service that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in the comments, the issue was that there was an action filter setup for the web api service which was causing the problem.

Comment: Why was the action filter causing this issue -- was it badly coded/buggy or its mere existence caused your client to break? If the former, then you're fine. If the latter, then you might still need a better solution to access your web api because what would happen if you absolutely must have an action filter? Anyway, just wanted to mention the [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) client. It specifically states in the [ReadMe](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) that it supports .NET 3.5 and later versions.