# Trace/Log SOAP XML Request and Response AND HTTP status code from SOAP .Net Client App

Tags: c#, .net, http, soap, soap-extension

I have C# .Net 2.0 App that is client of SOAP web services added to project through WebReferences. .Net creates convenient wrapper classes extending SoapHttpClientProtocol, so that everything like XML and serialization/deserialization of SOAP XML request/response in the communication is hidden.

I need to log the request and response to the WebServices and especially I want to have the HTTP status codes from the response the HTTP communication.

So far I have implemented SOAP Extension and to get the raw SOAP XML Requests/Responses, however I am unable to get the HTTP status code of the HTTP SOAP Response of the communication?

---

EDIT: So what I have is an instance of SoapHttpClientProtocol (generated by WSDL) and I want to get the HTTP status code from the communication.

I decompiled

```
private object[] ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, bool asyncCall)
```

Curiously there is this condition in it, which actually does not throw error when status 500?

```
if (num1 >= 300 && num1 != 500 && num1 != 400)
{
    throw new WebException(RequestResponseUtils.CreateResponseExceptionString(httpWebResponse, responseStream), null, WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError, httpWebResponse);
}
```

---

EDIT2:
So my problem generally is that I have response with HTTP status 500, which actually passes as success, without throwing WebException, due to the code above, which does not work for me, I want to detect such situation, that is why I need the HTTP status code.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Http wrapper of the request/response, you can try something like this [Call web APIs in C# using .NET framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397865/call-web-apis-in-c-sharp-using-net-framework-3-5).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am using .NET 2.0, this is legacy system. And I do not want to go for HttpWebRequest/Response classes (in fact I switched from them to web references, which gives me this limitation that now I cannot have the HTTP status code) and to compose/generate the XML myself. I ask if there is possible way to do this either from the SOAP extension, or I should write similar to *soap extension* for HTTP apporach?