# How to serialize Json object into System.Net.WebClient (.NET 3.5)

Tags: c#, .net

How can you serialize a json object and pass it on to an api call, like the one in the example posted as an answer here [Call web APIs in C# using .NET framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397865/call-web-apis-in-c-sharp-using-net-framework-3-5)

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
 client.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");//set your header here, you can add multiple headers
 string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(client.UploadData("http://localhost:1111/Service.svc/SignIn", "POST", Encoding.Default.GetBytes("{\"EmailId\": \"admin@admin.com\",\"Password\": \"pass#123\"}")));
```

In Postman I would just do this

```
 var client = new RestClient("");
 var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
 request.JsonSerializer = new RestSharpJsonNetSerializer();
 request.AddJsonBody(JsonObject);
```

However, as Postman is not supported in .net framework 3.5, I have to use System.Net.WebClient.

Comment: Why do you want to deserialize it? You need it in a serialized form to send it.

Comment: Question edited. I meant serialized, of course..

Comment: I think you don't need this- `Encoding.Default.GetBytes(`

Comment: In that case, look at Newtonsoft's JSON.Net - it's pretty much the de facto JSON serializer for .NET (to the point that even Microsoft use it).

Comment: I have NewtonSofts json in this project, the problem was more related to communicating it to the API, like in the Postman code provided.

Comment: You can use `string s = client.UploadString("..","POST", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject));`

Comment: Really that simple.. Huh, I thought of that, but thought there perhaps was a better approach. Add your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with `WebClient` (and Json.NET package) like this:

```
var yourObject = new YourObject {
    Email = "email",
    Password = "password"
};
string s = client.UploadString("http://localhost:1111/Service.svc/SignIn","POST", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject));
```

Comment: @miniHessel ah sorry I missed about .NET 3.5. Maybe there are indeed not much options there, not sure.

Comment: I think there isn't. Do you know how to check for status code like this   IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return true;  with WebClient?

Comment: Seems there is no direct way, but you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3574659/5311735. Though if response code is not successful (not in 2xx range) - it should throw an exception.